# Can't remove a specific completed task from a list

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
private static async Task ConcurrentTest()
{
    List<Task> subTasks = new List<Task>() { subTask() };
    while (subTasks.Count > 0)
    {
        Task nextTask = Task.WhenAny(subTasks);
        await nextTask;
        subTasks.Remove(nextTask);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("subTasks count "+subTasks.Count.ToString());
    }
}

private static async Task subTask()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!cancelTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test delay...");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if(i > 3)
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        ++i;
    }
    return;
}

static CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

subTasks.Remove(nextTask) can't remove the completed task.
```

I know that there is

```
subTasks.RemoveAll(x=>x.Iscompleted);
```

But I don't want to remove all the tasks that are completed at the instance of `RemoveAll` because I need to retrieve the results one by one.
Furthermore, I have looked at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx) article on MSDN.

Basically, it uses the same method.

Wonder why mine doesn't work.

**EDIT** oh my.. Suddenly realized how stupid the mistake I have made!!
just add an await like this would work...

```
Task nextTask = await Task.WhenAny(subTasks);
```

But thank you guys anyways.

Comment: Okay, so you have a list containing a single task. You create a new task representing the completion of any task in the list, then try to remove this newly created task, *which isn't in the list*. Why would this work? Could you explain more clearly what you're trying to do here?

Comment: `Task.WhenAny` does not return a task from the list that completed.  It returns a task that will complete when any task in the list completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WhenAny` returns a **new** task, that is completed when any of given tasks will be done. So it is a different instance than the one you've put into your list.

You can use [this `WhenAny` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160383%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will return the task that has completed as a result:

```
subTasks.Remove(nextTask.Result);
```

Or even simpler, as indicated by [Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad) in the comments:

```
subTasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(subTasks));
```

(instead of `Task nextTask = Task.WhenAny(subTasks);` and `await nextTask;`), because the [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh156528.aspx) keyword returns the *result* of the task, so in case of `WhenAny` the task that caused the operation to finish.

Comment: sorry for not being responsive. What if my tasks in subTasks return value say a dictionary<T>, I wouldn't be able to get any return value this way.

Comment: @CharlesParker `WhenAny` returns a compound task. Its `Result` is one of your tasks, which in turn contains what you want to be its result.

Comment: Also, `nextTask.Result` gives me error of no definition of Result.

Comment: @CharlesParker Are you using the overload I've given link to?

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation on WhenAny (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Creates a task that will complete when any of the supplied tasks have completed.

You can use Task.WaitAny which returns the index of the task that finishes, and use subTasks.RemoveAt(index)